# Make something happen if a specific time is left on DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, uwp, dispatchertimer

I'm currently working on a `UWP` project and need some help with my `DispatcherTimer`.

What I'm working with is a booking function and I want a color to change if there is 15 seconds left until the `DispatcherTimer` ticks.

I have two variables that is named `timefrom` and `timeTo` and they come from a `SQL` database. So what I want to do is to first change a color from `Green` to `Red` and then stay `Red` until there is 15 seconds left until the `timeto = DateTime.UtcNow`

```
"timefrom": "2018-02-17T14:00:00"
"timeto": "2018-02-17T15:15:00"
```

Right now, what I have tried with is this:

```
if (timeto < DateTime.UtcNow)
{
    StatusColor.Fill = GreenBrush;
}
else if (timeto > DateTime.UtcNow)
{
    GreenToRed();
}
```

This is my `DispatcherTimer`:

```
public void GreenToRed()
        {
            DispatcherTimer ColorTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            ColorTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
            ColorTimer.Tick += async (Sender, args) =>
            {
                await StatusColor.Fade(duration: 1000, delay: 0, value: 0).StartAsync();
                StatusColor.Fill = RedBrush;
                await StatusColor.Fade(duration: 1200, delay: 0, value: 1).StartAsync();
                RedToYellow();
                ColorTimer.Stop();
            };
            ColorTimer.Start();
        }
```

- StatusColor is a retangle that is suposed to contain the color as a
  fill.
- GreenBrush, RedBrush and YellowBrush is the three colors that I want
  to switch between.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What trouble are you experiencing? Using timers or calculating when it should fire?

Comment: I mean the problems I get is that it is not working, there is no errors at all but right now i can only set the `ColorTimer.Interval` to `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` and that sets a specific time... @Enigmativity

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Can you confirm that the timer is firing or not? Is it just that the colour isn't changing?

Comment: Yes the timer is working! But what i mean is that right now the timers interval is the same for every `Room`. So right now when the `Book` is happening I can only set one value. @Enigmativity

Comment: What's this about `Room`? There's nothing about rooms in your question. You really need to provide a [mcve] and a proper explanation about what's happening and what you want to happen. Perhaps read [ask] too?

Comment: But the `Room` isn't very important in this topic. Beacuse the only thing that I need help with is how to make the color change if there is 15 seconds until `timeto` is `DateTime.Now`. @Enigmativity

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what the issue is. Is it how to calculate the correct `TimeSpan`? Or is it that the colours aren't changing?

Comment: An [mcve] would let me know what's not working and save a lot of time.

Comment: It is the calculation of the correct `TimeSpan`. The colors are changing perfectly. Thank you for taking your time for this! @Enigmativity

Comment: Is this what you need? `var timeSpan = timeto.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15.0));`

Comment: Ok, I will est that and come back with an answer as soon as possible :)

Comment: Your solution is working prefectly! :) @Enigmativity